# Dropdwon menu not built with select tag

Tags: menu, dropdown

I have dropdown menu that I have to select Language from. The below its inspect details of the field.
I am trying to use By.cssSelector since I have realised I can't use Select as dropdown was not built in Select tag. The error am get is "element not interactable".

I used driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""#dropdownlistWrappercmbLanguage" > span")).sendKeys("English")
Please assist

ENGLISH

Comment: Can you post your dropdown menu code?